# C++ Tetris: A function that deletes lines

Tags: c++, tetris

I've been studying this tetris tutorial and I've come across the function that deletes lines and brings the row/s down one level. I'm kind of understanding what is going on with these functions, but some parts are confusing me. I'll try and explain it best I can, but here is the link to the lesson if you need it: http://javilop.com/gamedev/tetris-tutorial-in-c-platform-independent-focused-in-game-logic-for-beginners/

This, to me, looks like a function to get the array to start at the last number of a line:

```
void Board::DeleteLine (int pY)
{
    // Moves all the upper lines one row down
    for (int j = pY; j > 0; j--)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_WIDTH; i++)
        {
            mBoard[i][j] = mBoard[i][j-1];
        }
    }   
}
```

Then, there is the function that is causing me problems, which I will explain:

```
void Board::DeletePossibleLines ()
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 10)
        {
            if (mBoard[i][j] != 1) break;
            i++;
        }

        if (i == 10) DeleteLine (j);
    }
}
```

In case you're not familiar, the idea here is to delete a row that consists entirely of `1`. But `if (mBoard[i][j] != 1) break;` would stop the loop if the first line wasn't `1`. How would the loop reach a `1` that is somewhere in the middle of the `mBoard[][]` array if `break` stops it from doing anything possible straight away?

Am I missing something here? This is my interpretation of it. Perhaps somebody sees something I do't?

**Edit:**

Thanks for the replies, appreciated.

Comment: BTW, a cleaner implementation would have `bool Board::IsLineFull(int j) const`. And so, the loop would only contain `if (IsLineFull(j)) { DeleteLine(j); }`

Comment: @longAD for this, create a new Question please

Comment: It's ok Felix. I switched the i variable with the j variable and everything worked as I expected. Either the original author made a mistake, or more likely he inverted the width and height of his board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could structure the code like this aswell:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
{
 int i = 0;
    while (i < 10)
    {
        if (mBoard[i][j] != 1) 
        {
            break; //only breaks the while loop and will continue with if (i == 10)
        }
        else 
        {
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (i == 10)
    {
        DeleteLine (j);
    }
}
```

Now you can clearly see, that the `break;` is only interrupting your `while` loop but not your `for` loop.

Comment: @Quentin Indeed.  Quote:"Am I missing something here?"    My goal is to clarify the code, not to use Design Patterns and say how it should be done. That was not the Question

Comment: @FelixLahmer: I don't see the clarification of your version (and your indentation is worse than the original code).

Comment: @jarod42 when I learnt coding, I had problems understanding Code, when there werent brackets after the if etc

Comment: Use bracket if you want (I prefer to always have bracket too), but format correctly your code to clearly identify your block.

Answer (score 0):

`break` only interrupts *one* loop, the `while` loop in your case. The `for` loop continues happily.

On a side note, this `while` could easily (and should) be refactored into a `for`, and can be compacted according to its recognizable for-if-break pattern :

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10 && mBoard[i][j] == 1; ++i);

    if (i == 10) DeleteLine (j);
}
```

Comment: In fact, the `while` loop should be a method. And for variable with lifetime longer than the loop, a `for` loop is not necessary more readable (especially with empty body).

Comment: @Jarod42 slight edit. Compacting the loop was merely a suggestion, but it's indeed not the thing to do if you're not familiar with that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

The break will jump out of the while loop. So if you encounter a line which has a non-1 somewhere in the middle, *i* will be the index in the line, and the for loop will continue with the next line (*j*), starting with i=0 again.